# Executing receiveMessageRequest to the same SQS FIFO queue

Tags: java, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have two lambda instance running at the same time and these two instances will do a short poll to the same FIFO queue with only a few seconds apart.

The first instance will receive the first 10 messages and the second instance will receive 0 message even though there are a total of 15 messages in the queue.

Why couldn't the second instance get the remaining 5 messages from the queue? Is this the expected behaviour and how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 15 messages (most likely) all belong to the same Message Group ID. Therefore, the remaining 5 will not become available to your consumers until the first 10 are successfully processed and deleted. For FIFO Queues, this is the expected behaviour to preserve the order of messages (cheers @Michael-sqlbot for pointing in the right direction with this answer as per comments below).

Use [long polling](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-long-polling.html) for Standard Queues. Short polling doesn't check every SQS server, therefore, it has the potential to not get all results. Long polling does check all SQS servers and will therefore get all results.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already tried doing that. I set the value for `setWaitTimeSeconds` to 20 seconds and based on the logs it did poll for 20 seconds but there wasn't any message retrieved on the second lambda instance.

Comment: Fair enough, in theory that should do it. Did you try setting the `ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds` attribute on the queue itself?

Comment: @StevenS. Your answer would be exactly right, but this is a FIFO queue.  If the messages are all in one group, this is correct behavior for a FIFO queue.  Allowing another consumer to have messages from the same group would violate FIFO.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot OK, so the 5 missing messages have the same Message Group ID and the previous 10 messages of that group haven't yet been successfully processed and deleted. If they were a different Message Group ID, the second consumer could process them, but since they aren't, they don't become available until the first 10 are done.

Comment: StevenS. and @Michael-sqlbo. Thanks for the explanation!  I will go try it out soon and update it here.

Comment: Indeed, it was the Message Group ID that is causing the remaining 5 message to be irretrievable. I manage to find a way to workaround to this problem by playing with the message group id. Thank you very much!